# Showing ((a1 ⋄ a2) ⋄ a3) ⋄ a4 = a1 ⋄ (a2 ⋄ (a3 ⋄ a4)) in a semigroup.

Tags: linear-algebra, semigroups

I am a student in computer science - first year.
I study linear linear algebra 2 - course of linear algebra 1. - In some institutions academic studies teach the courses together / teach in another way.

I tried to solve the question a few hours but I'm not sure how to solve it exactly.

"4. (somewhat harder) Let G4 = (A, ⋄) be a semi-group, with |A| ≥ 4. Prove that
∀a1, a2, a3, a4 ∈ G4 : ((a1 ⋄ a2) ⋄ a3) ⋄ a4 = a1 ⋄ (a2 ⋄ (a3 ⋄ a4))."

There are two data in the question - a semi-group, and that A is an absolute value .greater than 4.
how A > 4 helps me solve the question, I did not understand how to use it at all. What does it actually help me?

Comment: $|A| \ge  4$ means $A$ has at least four elements. You are asked to prove that the distributive law as stated works for four elements given that by the definition of a semigroup it works for three. In tact the claim should be proved even if there aren't four distinct elements. The hypothesis on the size of $A$ is of no help.

Comment: In semi-group - the mathematical operation - is it associative? So order does not matter? thats it?

Comment: Order matters! In general $a*b \neq b*a$ (think about matrices), but $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c) = a*b*c$ (associativity) so you can choose to compute the "$a*b$" operation first or the "$b*c$" operation first.

Comment: i can say that:  ((a1 ⋄ a2) ⋄ a3) ⋄ a4 = a1 ⋄ (a2 ⋄ (a3 ⋄ a4)) equals to a1 ⋄ a2 ⋄ a3 ⋄ a4?

if no - so how i can prove it?

Comment: associativity somewhat means "you can omit the parentheses", but you have to prove that; luckily it's just a line of math

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$((a*b)*c)*d = (a*(b*c))*d = a*((b*c)*d) = a*(b*(c*d))$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{(}(a_1\diamond a_2)\diamond a_3\color{blue}{)}\diamond a_4&=\color{blue}{(}a_1\diamond \color{red}{(a_2\diamond a_3)}\color{blue}{)}\diamond a_4 \\
&=a_1\diamond \color{green}{(}\color{red}{(a_2\diamond a_3)}\diamond a_4\color{green}{)} \\
&=a_1\diamond \color{green}{(}a_2\diamond (a_3\diamond a_4)\color{green}{)}.
\end{align}